# Expression returning syntax error

Tags: python, regex, random

I was auditing some code at a local real estate company that has a severely outdated and hacked together system. Anyways I stumbled upon this error while trying to fix a very strange convoluted tag/comment sorting algorithm. I can't quite parse the code:

```
>>>''.join(re.findall("@(.{1})",'@'.join map(lambda x: x[::-1],['where are you a@', 'cruise queen mary on', 'morgtage ninjitsu', 'maritimes', 'professional analyst', 'blue ma', 'therapist or', 'forget-me-not'])))).upper
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can remove the `{1}`, it is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a missing parenthesis:

`'@'.join map(...` should be `'@'.join(map(...`

And `.upper` should be `.upper()`

So your final piece of code is:

```
''.join(re.findall("@(.{1})",'@'.join(map(lambda x: x[::-1], ['where are you a@', 'cruise queen mary on', 'morgtage ninjitsu', 'maritimes', 'professional analyst', 'blue ma', 'therapist or', 'forget-me-not'])))).upper()
```